# Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be complex matrices such that $C\neq 0, $ $AC=CB$. Prove that $A$ and $B$ have a common eigenvalue.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be complex matrices such that $C\neq 0, $ $AC=CB$. Prove that $A$ and $B$ have a common eigenvalue.

There is a hint in the question, these facts can be used for the prove:

- For a complex matrices $A, B$, If $AB = 0$, and $B$ is invertible, $A = 0$.
- For a complex matrices $A, B$ and $C$, if $AB = BC$ than for each natural number $k$, $\\\\A^kB = BC^k $.

Any ideas?

Comment: What if $C=0 $ ?

Comment: @Avishay28 do you want to recheck the question and edit?

Comment: I miss that, edited the question..

Comment: @Avishay28 do we know something about the invertibility of A and B?

Comment: @AdityaKumar No..

Comment: If C is invertible then the question is trivial as all eigenvalues will be same :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By induction, you show that $A^n C =CB^n$ for all $n$. Now take for $P$ the characteristic polynomial of $A$, by the above we deduce that $P(A)C=CP(B)=0$. If no eigenvalue of $B$ is a root of $P$, then $P(B)$ is invertible and $C=0$, contradiction.

Comment: That was clever :). I was thinking along the lines that det(A)=det(B) but was a dead end :/

Comment: can you kindly tell me is this is a standard technique or did you just think of it?

Comment: I have only used the hints given in your question...

Comment: @Kelenner Why P(B) must be invertible?

Comment: Let $P(x)=\prod(x-\lambda_k)^{n_k}$ where the $\lambda_k$ are distinct. If none of the $\lambda_k$ are eigenvalue of $B$, Then each of the $B-\lambda_kI$ are invertible, hence $P(B)$ is invertible as product of invertibles matrix.